# Как работает полиморфизм при работе с массивами дочерних объектов?

Tags: c++, наследование, интерфейс, полиморфизм, множественное-наследование

К примеру:

```
class interface
{
public: 
  virtual void do_something()
  {
     something..
  }
}

class base : public interface
{
public: 
  virtual void do_something()
  {
     somethingElse..
  }
}

class child : public interface, public base
{
public: 
  override void do_something()
  {
     somethingDifferent..
  }
}

class child2 : public interface, public base
{
public: 
  override void do_something()
  {
     somethingDifferent..
  }
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы объекты класов `child` и `child2`, к примеру находились в одном массиве. Если я создам массив элементов `base`, я смогу обращаться к ним через интерфейс? Или обязательно создавать массив объектов `interface`? Т. е. если я укажу тип данных `base` для массива, компилятор все равно выделит память под полный тип данных объекта включая `interface`? Или нет?

Comment: Массив может содержать только элементы одного типа, поэтому объекты класов child и child2 не могут находиться в одном массиве.

Comment: Насколько мне известно в массиве элементов базового класса могут храниться объекты дочерних классов, полиморфизм как-ни-как))

Comment: Полиморфизм тут не при чем, и в массиве элементов базового класса объекты других типов храниться не могут.

Comment: Блин, не знаю как код выложить. Но вы не правы, у меня такое компилируется

Comment: Оно компилируется, но в массиве будут только объекты базового типа. А компилируется оно потому, что вы забыли запретить конструкторы и операторы копирования / перемещения. `base obj; child cobj; obj = cobj;` у вас тоже будет компилироваться, но в переменной `obj` по-прежнему будет объект типа `base`. Инициализация и присвоение не могут изменить тип объекта. А код можно добавить отредактировав вопрос.

Comment: Ок, я понял. Никаких массивов) Это все походу из-за арифметики указателей да? Типа непрерывная область памяти и все такое?

Comment: Нет, это потому что массив является гомогенным контейнером, то есть по определению содержит только элементы одного типа. Аналогичный гетерогенный контейнер - это кортеж. При этом у обоих тип всех элементов зафиксирован во время компиляции.

Comment: Спасибо, погуглю!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы создадите массив объектов `base`, то, как вы понимаете, каждому объекту будет выделена память только под `base`, и вы получите при присваивании *срезку*.

Используйте массив указателей на `base` - и все получится :)

Еще - непонятно, зачем вы делаете `child` производным и от `base`, и от `interface`, при том, что `interface` является производным от `base`. Не то чтобы это было запрещено... но это очень специфичное решение, которое вряд ли вам необходимо, скорее, вы немного недоразобрались в вопросе.

Да, и `override` пишется с другой стороны объявления :)

Comment: Ахахах. Ну да, я еще разбираюсь. Мне нужно сделать так, потому что в коде уже все написано для объектов класса `base`, а интерфейс я только сейчас решил добавить) Много правок придется сделать. Аааа. Т. е. они автоматически наследуются, я понял))) Короче я сам запутался, но главное вы мне сказали, спасибо)